# Как черезе строку запрос сделать фильтрацию вывода?

Tags: laravel

У меня есть таблица пользователи и статуся, а также связывающая таблица.

Как через строку запроса например:
api/user?status=free

выводилсиьс бы только пользователи с этим статусом.

Я ни как не могу сообразить как вывести запиьс через связывающую таблицу

**user:**

id name

1  ivan

2  ilya

3  nina

**staus:**

id title

1  free

2  busy

3  unavailable

**user_Status:**

user_id  status_id

1        3

1        2

1        1

Контроллер

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $status = $request->get('status');
    $users = User::with('status')->get();
    
    return $users;

}
```

Comment: Как у вас реализовано отношение status в User? И создана ли модель для таблицы status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще странно что у Вас для статуса пользователя реализовано many to many отношение. Было бы более рационально использовать в модели User status_id, ну да ладно...

в модели User:

```
public function status()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Status::class);
}
```

в контроллере:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $status = $request->get('status');

    $users = User::query()
        ->when($status, function($q) use ($status){
             $q->whereHas('status', function($q) use ($status) {
                 $q->where('title', $status)
         })

    })->get();

    return $users;
}
```

P.S. код не проверял, если вдруг ошибочки - пишите, разберёмся.

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает!!!